Regular hexagon with right triangle inscribed in it
My friend ask me about this geometry problem.
Given a regular hexagon $ABCDEF$ with a inscribed right triangle $XYZ$ of sides length 3,4,5. The right angle $Y$ is at middle of $AB$, and $Z$ is at $CD$, $X$ is at $AF$. What will be the side length of the hexagon?

I am constructing an coordinate plane with origin be the center of hexagon and assume the side length is $l$, and then using distance formula to figure out the location of $z,x$ but I end up with some really messy equations.
Here is image of what my work:

So, I have three variables and three equations, I try to slove this by wolframalpha but it give me an really strange answer.
Any help will be appreciated!

Please include your work, even (or perhaps especially) with the "really messy equations". It may be possible for someone to nudge you to a complete solution (or spot an error) without having to duplicate your effort. ... Good luck!

@Blue sure, I will be happy to attach my work

FYI: A quick-and-dirty coordinate bash in Mathematica, seemingly confirmed with a GeoGebra sketch, indicates that the hexagon's side-length is $16\sqrt{3/97}$.

Interestingly, for a general right triangle $\triangle XYZ$ with $x=|YZ|$ and $z=|YX|$, and with hexagon half-side $a=|YA|=|YB|$, we have the relation $$\frac{1}{(a\sqrt{3}/2)^2} = \frac{1}{(x/3)^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}$$ (Note that $a\sqrt{3}/2$ is geometrically significant as half the length of the hexagon's apothem.) I wonder if there's a tidy demonstration of this.

Let $\ \overline{BY} = \overline{AY} = a\ $ and $\ \angle ZYB = \angle YXN = \theta\ $.

It can be easily derived that:
$$
\overline{PB} = 2a\quad\
 \overline{PY} = 3a\quad\ 
\sqrt{3}\cdot\overline{PM} = \overline{MZ} \quad\
\sqrt{3}\cdot\overline{AN} = \overline{XN}
$$
$$
\overline{MZ} = 4\cdot\sin\theta \quad\
\overline{MY} = 4\cdot\cos\theta \quad\
\overline{YN} = 3\cdot\sin\theta \quad\
\overline{XN} = 3\cdot\cos\theta \quad\
$$
Then considering:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\overline{PM} + \overline{MY} &= \overline{PY} \\
\overline{NY} - \overline{YA} &= \overline{AN} \\
\end{aligned} 
$$
We have equations:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot 4\cdot\sin\theta + 4\cdot\cos\theta &= 3a \\
3\cdot\sin\theta - a &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot 3\cdot\cos\theta \\
\end{aligned}
$$
I don't have a clever way to solve the above equations. But the final answer is the same as what @Blue has commented.

Your two equations form a linear system in $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$. You can solve for those, then substitute into $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ to get an equation in $a$.
